# Does lowering the ride height of a car 50 mm exactly lower the height of C.G by 50 mm?

Tags: car, centre-of-gravity

Does lowering the ride height of a car $50\ mm$ exactly lower the height of C.G. by $50\ mm$ or is it higher?

Comment: No, because all the weight present affects the COG. So while moving only some of the weight lower does move the COG lower, it always move a smaller distance because you didn't move all the other weight as well.

Answer (score 7):

No. All the wheels, axles, brakes and parts of the suspension would remain in the same position relative to the ground so their contribution to the centre of gravity doesn't change. The overall CoG will decrease by < 50 mm.

[image]

*Figure 1. For your calculations you can just consider the heights of the two CoGs when calculating the overall CoG.*

Comment: Sorry didn't know! So it will be less than 50 but will the number be close to 50? I don't have instruments to measure this that's why.

Comment: Define 'close'?

Comment: You'll need to model it. Find the CoG of the parts that stay fixed relative to the road and the CoG of the rest of the car. Then it's simple to find the combined CoG for the two situations. Most 3D CAD software can do this for you. Try http://onshape.com for a free in-the-browser software (if your designs are public) and see if it will calculate CoG for you. There may be some reasonable car models for you to play with.

Comment: @Nerdforferraris Yes. The ratio will be weight of the suspended part of the car to parts fixed relative to the road - meaning on one side the car body, engine, most of mass. On the other side, wheels, their axles, the road-side part of suspension etc. I'd be surprised if that's more than 10%, so >45 is definitely in the ballpark for common cars. (Monster Trucks, tractors etc may exceed that.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the equation to calculate the height H of  CG of a car.

$$ h=\frac{ \Sigma m_n *h_n}{  \Sigma m_n}$$

Or a weighted sum of contributory parts divided by the mass of the car.

In most cars this ratio is approximately 65% super structure and 35% suspension and drivetrain components that are fixed to suspension. So if we lower the cab by 50 mm we lower the overall CG by approximately 35mm.

To make matters more complicated some parts and links are connected to both, such as shocks, springs, steering rods and anti-roll bars.